# Solana hello_world problem on Windows 10/WSL2/Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wsl-2, solana

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld).

I'm running a WSL2 Ubuntu18.04 machine in a Windows 10 system and am stuck when running this line:

`$ solana-test-validator`

This is the output I get:

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Unable to connect to validator: Client error: test-ledger/admin.rpc does not exist
```

Any clues about what can be wrong?

Comment: Nothing at that point in the tutorial has anything to do with Rust; you're just dealing with the Solana configuration. It doesn't even look like this is an actual programming problem at this point.

Comment: Since Solana is a Javascript library, it feels pretty on-topic to me.

Comment: So, I think I found out what it was. I just reinstalled the whole WSL, after that when reinstalling the necessary dependencies for the tutorial (nodejs, npm, rust and solana) make sure to change directories to the WSL home folder (by default it opens on the mounted windows system). Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @MartinRouret That makes sense.  I was looking for any indication in the output that `/mnt/c` was involved, but not seeing any, I didn't figure that was the problem.  But yeah, WSL has some limitations in regards to 9P protocol (used to access Windows drives), and one of those must have bit you.  I recommend you add this to a self-accepted answer.  Thanks!

Comment: if anyone got here because they are confused what repo is the repo mentioned in this Figment solana pathway step https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/setup-the-project#set-your-datahub-a-p-i-key

it's this https://github.com/figment-networks/learn-web3-dapp

Answer (score 12):

So do follow this link for more explanation
https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/issues/294

But to clarify something that was not clear for me from this Answer. All you need to do is run the solana-test-validator from the home dir in your WSL2. I did not need to reinstall all of the dependencies to get it running correctly.

When starting your WSL terminal the starting directory is `/mnt/c/...` you need to `cd ~/` and then run solana-test-validator.

Comment: You save my day.

Comment: I don't get it why but yeah. That solved my issue too

Answer (score 2):

Before running solana-test-validator,
you need to `cd ~/` and then run solana-test-validator.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I just reinstalled the whole WSL, after that when reinstalling the necessary dependencies for the tutorial (nodejs, npm, rust and solana) make sure to change directories to the WSL home folder (by default it opens on the mounted windows system).

https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld/issues/294 (Github issue with more info)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it is solved by downgrading solana-cli from `v1.8.3` to `v1.7.17`.

It troubled be for several days.

It may not be the same condition to this question.

But I help it will help someone.